# how to test persisting entity with not nullable collection

Tags: hibernate, testing, collections, persistence, dao

I'm learning how to write test cases and I've encounter a problem.
I have a persistence unit with entityA that has not empty collection of  Bs. 
The application workflow ensures that B is never empty and contains entities that have already been persisted.
(Let's say a user has to choose email addresses from his address book)

Now I have a problem in testing persisting A. 
If I create A i must create a set of Bs (@NotNull). 
B doesn't exist in test db so I get an error "object references an unsaved transient instance".

I'm using dbunit so the question is: 
Is it all right to use entitymanager and select set of Bs, that have been loaded for test from xml files, then add them to A and persist A? It somehow doesn't sound like a unit test to me. What is the best practice to handle this situation

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any other possibility. A has a dependency to B, so you need to have Bs in order to persist A. Since mocking is not possible in this case, you need to get your Bs from the database.

Comment: I have one more nuisance with this test. EM Queries return List and in the entities collections are declared as Set. Can I overcome this problem? Obviously I can't do conversion because the result will be treated as different object. How does one test collections that are sets?

Comment: I usually use a utility methods testing that the set contains an entity with a given ID. Or I just transform it as a list, sort the list by ID, and test every element of the list.

Comment: My problem is that to persist A I must  initialize it with already persisted set of B. so I have get/set methods that use Set<B> as parameter/return and JPA Queries return List.

Comment: So what? Just use new HashSet<B>(listOfBs).